# Mscorlib unable to find dependencies throwing FileLoadException

Tags: c#, exception

I have a webApi project that was throwing an exception about being unable to find `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource` library. I Added reference to the nuget packages with this file. But now I'm getting:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 
>   'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.2.0,
>   Culture=neutral, 
>       PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's
>        manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'

Version I have in "packages" folder is **4.6.25519.03**

How do i fix this issue?

csproj reference:

```
    <Reference Include="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.2.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.4.4.1\lib\net46\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

Comment: Could you please provide your csproj section for System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource?

Comment: @IsmailYilmaz I updated the question with the csproj reference

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe your packages location is wrong. Try to use "..\packages\" instead of "..\..\packages" please.

Comment: i re-referenced it thru visual studio, problem is still there

Comment: Hmm version numbers.. "Version=4.0.2.1" and "..\..\packages\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.4.4.1" and you have 4.6.25519.03 in your packages. As i know those version numbers should be the same. As specially in csproj.

Comment: I think it is mscorlib looking for that specific version, not sure how to make it use anything different

Comment: Share with us your source code on github if it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Version` attribute *does not* have to match the version number in the packages folder for that package. In fact mine are set to

```
<Reference Include="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.4.5.0\lib\net46\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

and the product version on the assembly is set to **4.6.26515.6** and I don't get any errors or warnings during compilation and the assembly is found at runtime.

What I suggest is

- Update the package (it appears you're using an older version).
- Check for other referenced versions against all your projects. Sometimes there will be multiple versions because someone managed packages at a project rather than a solution level.
- Check the dependencies of your other NuGet packages; it's possible they are referencing other versions and this is causing the .NET assembly probing to try and load the wrong version. You can use the [AssemblyBinding Log Viewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) to try and diagnose this. Also, try updating those packages.

If these don't help, consider adding a [binding redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions) to your `app.config` file.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling nuGet package and it fixed the issue